# Caching with Squid not working for docker images - why?

Tags: docker, caching, squid

(my first question, so please be patient)

- I have a running Squid proxy with caching and ssl-bump, self signed root-CA etc.
- I have several Ubuntu systems which are configured to use the Squid proxy
- I configured the docker on Ubuntu to also use the proxy via the official documentation https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

In general Squid and cache are working fine. On Ubuntu machines Browser downloads are cached (2nd try to download is fast and from cache), apt install packages and also snap applications are cached.

My problem is the docker. It is working in general and using the proxy:

- When proxy is disabled, docker pull cannot connect, so no bypassing of the proxy
- When pulling an image, squid cache is filling/size increasing
- But when pulled the 2nd time the same image, it is downloading again from Internet and is not taking from the cache

Set Squid to debug mode and tried to analyze the cache logs, but cannot make a clue out of it.

Any ideas what else to try/change? Is this a Squid/config problem or not possible at all?

And please, I am aware of docker proxy and and other projects which try to do exactly this, caching registries and if I will fail with Squid I will probably go that way, but in first place I want to make it with existing squid or be sure it is not possible.

Thanks
Chris

my squid conf:

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT


#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
#http_port 3128 #default without ssl
http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/cygdrive/d/squid/etc/squid/myca.pem

#security_file_certgen -c -s d:\squid\var\cache\squid\ssl_db -M 4MB
sslcrtd_program /cygdrive/d/squid/lib/squid/security_file_certgen -s /cygdrive/d/squid/var/cache/squid_ssldb -M 4MB
#sslcrtd_children 5
#ssl_bump server-first all
#sslproxy_cert_error deny all


#HTTPS Part
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3

acl ssl_exclude_domains ssl::server_name "/cygdrive/d/squid/etc/squid/ssl_exclude_domains.conf"
acl ssl_exclude_ips     dst              "/cygdrive/d/squid/etc/squid/ssl_exclude_ips.conf"

ssl_bump splice localhost
ssl_bump peek step1 all
ssl_bump splice ssl_exclude_domains
ssl_bump splice ssl_exclude_ips
ssl_bump stare step2 all
ssl_bump bump all

sslproxy_cert_error allow all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER

#max file size
maximum_object_size 6 GB

# Uncomment the line below to enable disk caching - path format is /cygdrive/<full path to cache folder>, i.e.
#cache_dir ufs /cygdrive/d/Squid/var/cache/squid 3000 16 256
cache_dir ufs /cygdrive/d/Squid/squidcache 3000 16 256


# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222

max_filedescriptors 3200
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your squid.conf before the refresh_pattern line that references /cgi-bin/

```
refresh_pattern -i (/blobs/sha256)     1440 99% 10080  ignore-no-store ignore-private override-expire store-stale reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i (/images/sha256)    1440 99% 10080  ignore-no-store ignore-private override-expire store-stale reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i (/manifests/)       1440 99% 10080  ignore-no-store ignore-private override-expire store-stale reload-into-ims
```